# Django Serializer - Combine fields from two models

Tags: django

I have two models namely:

```
class B (models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class A (models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

I want a serializer which returns a response like this:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "test",
   "b_id": 2,
   "b_name": "test
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the response format you want to get is not possible to my knowledge but you can use `nestedSerializers` to get both models in one response like

```
    {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "test",
       "b":{
           "id":"test",
           "name": "test"
            }
    }
```

if this is enough for you you can use the following code

**serializers.py**

```
class Bserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
         model = B
         fields = "__all__" #or only the fields you want

class Aserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       b = Bserializer()
       class Meta:
         model = B
         fields = ["id","name", "b"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `b` field in `A` model is a one to many relation so it should be a list of a items like this, also check [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)

```
{
   "b_id": 1,
   "b_name": "test",
   "a": [
       'a_id1': 'a_name',
       'a_id2': 'a_name'
   ]
}
```

If that is what you want you can do it like this:

```
class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is directly from a project im working on now

```
class CoachLocationsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    base = LocationSerializer(read_only=True)
    locations = LocationSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Coach
        fields = ['base', 'locations']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it without using nested serializers, like this:

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    b_name = serializers.CharField(source='b__name')

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'b_id', 'b_name')
```

Also, note that you don't need to declare `b_id` in the serializer, since it's already a model field